# Logarithmic function in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am currently working on a growth model with the lme package of the statistical software R. I've already built models with a linear and `poly(Time,2)` trend, whereas the latter fits better. Additionally, I would like to test for a logarithmic trend but don't know what the function in R looks like or how to transform it as most guides only cover linear, quadratic, cubic trends but exclude logarithmic ones.

Therefore, I would highly appreciate if someone could help me out and provide me with a function for a logarithmic trend.

In order to make it more clear what I'm currently doing -> my current models look like:

```
model.linear<-lme(DV~1+Time,random=~1|Subnum,data=dataset,na.action=na.omit,control=list(opt="optim"))

model.quadratic<-lme(DV~poly(Time,2),random=~1|Subnum,data=dataset,na.action=na.omit,control=list(opt="optim"))
```

Comment: `lme(DV~log(Time),...)`??

Comment: Also, you don't need `1+Time` in your linear model; `R` includes the constant unless you tell it not to, e.g. by including `Time-1`. See `?formula`

Comment: Thanks for responding!

I already tried the (DV~log(Time),...) version but it appears an error message: 
Error in array(c(rep(1, p), .C(inner_perc_table, as.double(X), as.integer(unlist(grps)),  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Comment: That means you've probably got values of `Time` equal to 0 or negative.

Comment: Aaah, indeed, my Time values are 0,1,2. Any idea how I can circumvent that?

Comment: this is becoming more statistics than programming, have you browsed for similar questions on Cross Validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
model.logistic<-lme(DV~log1p(Time),random=~1|Subnum,data=dataset,na.action=na.omit,control=list(opt="optim"))
```

The function `log1p()` adds 1 to each observation before logging it, which works well with count variables or other variables with a lower bound of 0 and whole-number increments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ulfelder! That did the trick.
I also played around a bit and came to the following model (also adding 1 to each observation but not as smooth as yours), which has exactly the same results as with yours.
    `model.logistic<-lme(DV~log(Time+1),random=~1|Subnum,data=dataset,na.action=na.omit,control=list(opt="optim"))`

Comment: Right, `log1p(x)` is mathematically identical to `log(x + 1)`.